# Regression for arrays rather than numerical values

Tags: regression, cnn

I have a dataset with a small amount of points (~500) and 10 features. The points are related to eachother, so that information about point 1 should help predict information about point 2 etc etc.
Leaving aside the low number of points, I  was thiking of feeding a CNN triplets of points (3x10 features) in the form of a 2D array, some pooling and dense layers in the middle and in the end a Dense layer of 3 as my output.

By now the results are very poor, but I guess with 370 data points (they reduce in number going from single point to triplets) i Couldn't expect a lot.

Are there other ways not involving CNN to do regression of triplets of points? What would you suggest?

Comment: Can you add another variable which identifies these triplets? Are the triplets overlapping?

Comment: If they are related to each other, can you use distance-based methods, like k-nearest neighbors, kernel-ridge regression, Gaussian process?